# Remove an item from a list if it only contains one word

Tags: python, list

How would I remove an item from a list if it only has one word?
Ex:

```
my_list = ['how is it going today?','good','the','It is nice weather outside']
```

I am thinking something like my_list.pop but it needs to be based on a condition of only one word.  In this case, I need 'good' and 'the' removed from my_list.  Any ideas?
the output I am expecting is:

```
print(my_list)
['how is it going today?','It is nice weather outside']
```

Comment: How is "one word" defined? Is `one,word` one word or two?

Comment: That would be two words, but I am thinking most the time more than one word appears there will be whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of the list resulting from splitting the string, e.g.:

```
my_list = ['how is it going today?','good','the','It is nice weather outside',' word']
my_list = [x for x in my_list if len(x.strip().split()) > 1]


print(my_list)
# ['how is it going today?', 'It is nice weather outside']
```

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is removing trailing whitespaces, while [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is dividing the string into whitespace-separated substrings.
This is is not very efficient because it is creating a temporary `list`, which can be avoided in a number of common scenarios.

---

If you can assume that separators are not present at the beginning and/or end of the string, a more efficient approach (which would work for multi-char separators) would be:

```
separators = ' ', '\t', '\n'  # etc.


my_list = ['how is it going today?','good','the','It is nice weather outside',' word']
my_list = [
    x for x in my_list
    if any(separator in x for separator in separators)]


print(my_list)
# ['how is it going today?', 'It is nice weather outside', ' word']
```

---

If you can assume that separators are single-chars, an efficient approach that is robust against trailing `separators` would be:

```
separators = ' \t\n'  # etc.


my_list = ['how is it going today?','good','the','It is nice weather outside',' word']
my_list = [
    x for x in my_list
    if any(separator in x.strip(separators) for separator in separators)]


print(my_list)
# ['how is it going today?', 'It is nice weather outside']
```

Comment: I really like this.  Can you explain a little further what is actually happening?  Is this checking for whitespace?

Comment: @acodejdatam I have added some explanations and some solutions that should be more efficient under some specific assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension and the fact that if there's more than one word in the phrase there must be at least one space as well. The following line would achieve that:

```
my_list = [phrase for phrase in my_list if phrase.count(' ') > 0]
```

If your definition of "more than one word" doesn't fit with how I've defined it (must contain at least one space) then you can modify the if statement depending on your logic.

Comment: This is a very efficient and elegant solution, if one can assume that no whitespaces other than `' '` are present and that the whitespaces are at neither ends of the word, otherwise `' word'` would fail the test, while being a single word.

Comment: Indeed. May actually be cleaner to do it with a regex - then you could capture all types of white space, can rule out the space at the start and end AND can check for the presence of other potential "word breaking" characters (|,;:).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @the_martian's answer, but we can also try a different approach:

```
my_list = [phrase for phrase in my_list if ' ' in phrase]
```

Comment: This is actually more efficient than `count() > 0`, because `count()` needs to go through the entire string to complete regardless of the input, while `in` could terminate as soon as `' '` is found.

Answer (score -1):

```
for index, ele in enummerate(my_list):
   words = ele.split(' ')
   if(len(words)==1):
      my_list.pop(index)
```